# Auto install program with stdin

Tags: bash

I want to install the program `azure client 2.0` from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli) which is done with

```
curl -L https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCli | bash
```

automatically in a bash script. 
The problem I have is, that during the installation process, different questions regarding locations are asked and some input must be provided.
Is it possible to pass all inputs already at the beginning (pre-defined) so that it can install without any user involvement?

Comment: is it the same answer (e.g. "Yes") or several different answers?

Comment: It's yes and a couple more...

Answer (score 0):

You could use an expect script.

using "autoexpect -P " the script will be generated automatically as you go through it.

However you actually have to run the command and go through it first to generate the script.